# What's the correct pronunciation for Luffy or Rufi?

Tags: one-piece

What's the correct pronunciation of his name? Luffy or Rufi?

[At the One Piece wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy), it says "Monkey D. Luffy (モンキー･D･ルフィ Monkī D. Rufi)".

Comment: Btw it's differenty in some languages. The official translation in German is "Ruffy".

Comment: In [the IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet): something like [mõŋ̩k̟ii　dii　ɽɯ̟͡β̞ɸi] (narrow transcription)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer needs a premise.

You see, Japanese don't distinguish between the L and R sounds. The L doesn't really exist and the R is not pronounced like in English. It's more similar to the Italian/Spanish R but it's not rolled. Also, FI doesn't belong to the standard Kana — ha, hi, hu (fu), he, ho — but it's constructed.

Based on this, you could say both (and probably for Japanese there really isn't a difference like for us). But apparently Oda meant the name to be **Luffy** (can't find a source yet), and since the Japanese language cannot faithfully represent this name it became *Rufi*, being the closest match to the actual name.

Answer (score 2):

Luffy is the official spelling, which you can see printed on official merchandise.

「ルフィ」 (*rufi*) is the Japanese pronunciation of this name. The first syllable of it is **pronounced by the average Japanese person as an [alveolar tap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_tap)** (written in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/learn-english/pronunciation/vowels-phonetics/) (IPA) as the fishhook-shaped **ɾ** symbol. Note how this symbol subtly differs from the English **r** letter) plus an **"oo" sound** (as in "root," "google," etc. Written in the IPA as "u" or in the standard symbol as ū. See the English Language & Usage SE for details on "u" [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36905/why-are-there-3-different-ways-to-pronounce-oo)).

The Japanese syllabograms *ra, ri, ru, re,* and *ro* (ラ、リ、ル、レ、ロ、 or in hiragana, ら、り、る、れ、ろ) are alveolar taps, which are a type of [liquid consonant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_consonant) that sound rolled. They **do not directly correspond to any English letter** such as R (which is written in the IPA as [image] . Notice that phonetically it is not the same as the thin fishhook-shaped **ɾ** symbol). An alveolar tap **can sound approximately like *any* of the following English letters: R, L, or D**. In Japanese pronunciation, it is **equally acceptable** to pronounce 「ルフィ」 sounding like a rolled R, a non-rolled R, an L, or a D.

Since many native English speakers do not grow up exposed to listening to the alveolar tap, many think they are hearing an R or L while listening to Japanese and therefore romanization of Japanese into romaji uses "r". This is the exact inverse of some Japanese people hearing an English R or L and thinking that they are hearing an alveolar tap. [**Some Japanese can distinguish the difference**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perception_of_English_/r/_and_/l/_by_Japanese_speakers#Perception) in listening to the English R versus L versus alveolar tap, even though they cannot accurately replicate  R and/or L, while some Japanese cannot hear the difference. Some can pronounce the difference between R and L. Some cannot originally distinguish and pronounce the difference but [can learn to via phonetics training](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perception_of_English_/r/_and_/l/_by_Japanese_speakers#Effects_of_training).

The natural English pronunciation of the spelling "Luffy" would most likely be with an L sound and a short "uh" sound (as in "ruff, "just," etc. Written in the IPA as [image] or in the standard symbol as ŭ). However, **such an intended pronunciation would have been written** in katakana as 「ラフィ」 (*rafi*) with an "ah" sound (as in "call," "also," etc. Written in the IPA as [image] or in the standard symbol as ô), so we can deduce that Oda did not have "luh" in mind as the correct pronunciation.

「フィ」 is a [glide](http://japanese.gatech.edu/WebCTVista/JAPN1001/contents/Lesson02/katakana/2.7.html) (not unlike a [diphthong](http://www.fonetiks.org/sou3ja.html) slide) of 「フ」 (*fu* or *hu*) + 「イ」 (*i*) = "*fui*" sped up becomes "*fi*". It is analogous to the long I sound (as in "sunny," ski," etc. Written in the IPA as "i" or in the standard symbol as ē).

In International Phonetic Alphabet, 「ルフィ」 is pronounced **ɾ u f i**. To present this in perhaps an easier-to-read spelling, we could write "roo + fee" where the "r" is rolled (as much or as little close to an English L as you like).