# What's the name of One Piece's principal character?

Tags: one-piece

In the Brazilian subtitle, he was first called as Ruffy, but in the half of Enies Lobby/Water 7 Saga he started being called as Luffy, so I'm interested in knowing what is his name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His name is Luffy.  You better know his name when he becomes King of the Pirates!

We have discussed the difference with regard to pronounciation on this site [before](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/782/whats-the-correct-pronunciation-for-luffy-or-rufi).

Comment: Note that I answered this rather than marked it as a duplicate because this question is about spelling, not pronounciation.  It is not, therefore, a true duplicate.