# Where did it become known that Rin's and Len's names have different first letters?

Tags: japanese-language, vocaloid

According to [the answers here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/782/1587) and [this chat post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26044041#26044041)

> there's one sound in Japanese which is somewhere between L and R, though probably closer to R.

- Luffy/Ruffy (One Piece)
- Lio/Rio (Kara no Kyoukai)

2 of the Vocaloids are the twins Rin and Len, but given the above, their names could be Rin and Ren, Lin and Len, or even Lin and Ren.

So where did it become known that Rin's and Len's names have different first letters, as opposed to the alternatives that I mentioned?

Comment: Probably word of god. Seeing as their names are written on the software box and all.
http://www.amazon.com/Vocaloid2-Character-Vocal-Series-02/dp/B001BIXLOC

Comment: These days there's usually a "word of god" official transliteration of character names. In the past though, it could vary depending on who was doing translation. It's more than just L/R as well. The names リン and レン correspond to a number of different western names, like Lynn and Wren.

Comment: Also, a theory for this particular case: the name's depict **Ri**ght and **Le**ft speakers/channels/whatever-it-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [earliest archived revision](https://web.archive.org/web/20071223223624/http://www.crypton.co.jp/mp/pages/prod/vocaloid/cv02.jsp#) of [Crypton's page for the Kagamines](http://www.crypton.co.jp/mp/pages/prod/vocaloid/cv02.jsp) that reveals details about them has their names in both Latin script and in Japanese.

[image]

That revision is from 3 Dec 2007, which is shortly before they were actually first sold later that same month.

So I guess the answer to your question is that it was known to people pretty much from the very beginning.